# Allow program to be executed with execvp

Tags: c, path, exec, search-path

I'm creating a shell copy and I have a problem to executable an homemade program. I mean, everything is OK when I want to execute somethings like `java`, `ls`, `wc`, etc... everything that is already present in the PATH variable.

Now I want to be able to execute a "myls" command which is a copy of the original `ls`. The thing is that my program isn't registered in PATH variable, so when I try to `execvp("myls", …)`, I get an error "no such file or directory".

I would like to know how can I manage this problem and be able to execute my command according this hierarchy :

```
src
include
bin
makefile
executable <- this one is my main executable
myLs
    executableLS <- would like to be able to call this one through execvp
myPs
    executablePS <- would like to be able to call this one through execvp
```

Comment: Either put your programs in a directory that is on your `$PATH` or put the directory where the programs are on your `$PATH`, or use an appropriate pathname (relative or absolute) to identify the program to be run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow a program to be executed with `execvp()`, you must:

- Either put your programs in a directory already on your `$PATH`,
- Or put the directory where the programs live on your `$PATH`,
- Or arrange to use the absolute pathname to the programs (`/some/where/useful/myLs`),
- Or arrange to use a correct relative pathname to the programs (`../useful/myLs` or even `./myLs`).

Note that `execvp()` only searches on `$PATH` when the command name it sees contains no `/` (so `./myLs` stops it looking on `$PATH`).  The relative names are typically least useful; if you change directory, it is likely that the relative pathname changes.

In case of doubt, make sure you have a directory `$HOME/bin`, put your programs in there (or symlinks to your programs in there), and add `$HOME/bin` to your path.  It lives at the front of my PATH; I assume I know what I'm doing.

Comment: Oh yeah it’s exactly what i was looking for ! Thank you everything is working now !